# How do I update? Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

So yeah I'm new and I need some help. I have 2 textfields that have text on them and I want those 2 strings (username,password) to be updated in my database. I have no idea on how to ask it because I don't know how this thing works. Completely new to Xcode. Please do understand. Thanks! btw, here is my code atm.

```
@interface ViewController4 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController4

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.lbName.text=self.strName;
    self.lbUser.text = self.strUsername;

    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT username,password FROM SUMMARY8 WHERE name = '%s' and theuser = '%s'",[self.lbName.text UTF8String],[self.lbUser.text UTF8String]];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare(account, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
        char *field1=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0 );
        self.tbUsername.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];
            char *field2=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1 );
            self.tbPassword.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];


    }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) openDB
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &account) !=SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(account);
        NSAssert(0,@"Database failed to open");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"account.sql"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnEdit:(id)sender {
    self.btnEdit.enabled=NO;
    self.tbUsername.enabled=YES;
    self.tbPassword.enabled=YES;
    self.btnUpdate.hidden=FALSE;

}
- (IBAction)btnReturn:(id)sender {
   FlipsideViewController *FVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FlipsideViewController"];
     FVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    FVC.strUsername=self.strUsername;
    [self presentViewController:FVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnUpdate:(id)sender {

    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE SUMMARY8 SET username='1',password='2' WHERE name = '%s' and theuser = '%s'",[self.lbName.text UTF8String],[self.lbUser.text UTF8String]];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare(account, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

    }


}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [[self tbUsername]resignFirstResponder];
    [[self tbPassword]resignFirstResponder];

}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: So you are saying you have no idea how the above code (written by you) work?

Comment: so is it working or there is a problem?

Comment: I just need to know how to do the codes for the updating

- (IBAction)btnUpdate:(id)sender {

    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE SUMMARY8 SET username='1',password='2' WHERE name = '%s' and theuser = '%s'",[self.lbName.text UTF8String],[self.lbUser.text UTF8String]];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare(account, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

    }
}

dunno how..

Comment: Which parts are giving you trouble? What steps are you stuck on? To get the best answers, make sure to have your questions be specific to the problems you are having. It's tough for people to answer very broad questions, and questions like these will be closed, anyways. Good luck and hope you are able to get some good questions answered!

Comment: @LorenzdeGuzman Even if someone helps you with the code, it won't help you in the long run. You do yourself a very good favor by reading about SQLite3 database and queries and try to understand them.

Comment: This objective C is far from what language I'm used to which is C#. I did read alot about that SQLite3 but still don't know how to do it on my own so I was seeking for help if someone out there could teach me. I already have completely understood the SELECT,INSERT,DELETE statements but not the UPDATE stmt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I will do(change it accordingly):

```
-(void)updateStatus:(NSString *)queryString {
    NSString    *docsDir;
    NSArray     *dirPaths;
    dirPaths    = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir     = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    strDatabasePath         = [NSString stringWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: strDatabasePath] == YES)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [strDatabasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqlDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char* beginString = "BEGIN;";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDatabase, beginString, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {}
            else DLog(@"Failed!");
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);

            DLog(@"QUERY : %@",queryString);

            const char *selectStatement = [queryString UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDatabase, selectStatement, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL);
            //sqlite3_bind_text(compiledstatement,1,[statusString UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if (sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {}
            else DLog(@"Failed!");
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);


            const char* endString="END;";
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDatabase, endString, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {}
            else DLog(@"Failed!");
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);

            sqlite3_close(sqlDatabase);
        }
        else DLog(@"Failed to open table");
    }
}

NSString *queryString;
queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE SUMMARY8 SET username='1',password='2' WHERE name = '%s' and theuser = '%s'",[self.lbName.text UTF8String],[self.lbUser.text UTF8String]];
[self updateStatus:queryString];
```

I hope you get the idea.. Pass the querystring(update sql statement) to the function which will touch the database to do the updating. Next time, you have the same update statement, just create the queryString and pass it to the function.